# Are confirmed US deaths being posted anywhere?

Tags: covid-19, statistics

The [CDC website on cases and mortality involving COVID-19](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html) currently says reads "Data include both confirmed and presumptive positive cases of COVID-19.

Is there anywhere that they are breaking this out and published confirmed and presumptive separately?

Answer (score 0):

*Presumptive cases* is referring to the infected. There are not enough test kits for all. The diagnosis is    based on symptoms. So we know only the sum of tested and symptomatic cases. *1)

From the dead we can know the absolute numbers.
But they we can never be sure that they are absolutely right as meanwhile they can have been doubled.

*1) I was assuming that even in China at least the victims who died have been tested.

https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am trying to find where, if anywhere, the CDC is publishing the confirmed deaths (meaning those who died and tested positive) as opposed to the combined confirmed and presumptive death cases.

Comment: This is really an interesting point that I was asking myself too! The first dead we had in Switzerland were 1.  an old woman with multiple deceases 2. an old man that wouldn’t receive medicaments 3. a victim with cancer. Finally they caught the virus. From what did they die now?